# make a progressBar

Tags: android, progress-bar, progress

I want to add a ProgressBar to my project, I get the following error: **CAN NOT RESOLVE SYMBOL LOADING**.

see below my code, 
help me plz

```
 public void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }

    mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: add the loading string to the string file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just press `alt + enter` in loading and select `Create string value resource "loading"` and then write the `Resource Value` of the string, just put in `Resource Value: loading`

also inside setMessage you can work with a string like this

```
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
```

but is a good practice to use Strings than hardcodeding strings.

You can follow this images

First alt + enter into loading

[image]

Then just write Loading... inside Resource Value

[image]

Then you can go to your `Strings.xml` that is inside `res  - values` and see that yoru String is there

[image]

Comment: dont forget to check my answer if that helped :) happy codding

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because it can´t find the string loading from the resources, check if it´s correctly spelled if it´s try to re-build the gradle and the sync the project.

Answer (score 0):

You can enter direct text here

```
mProgressDialog.setMessage("Your Text");
```